# Issue with Node.js, Express, Socket.IO, in React not working for one small issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have an Ionic, Typescript React project I am working on using MongoDB , Node, Express, and Socket.IO. My issue is with my friends list displaying online/offline status of users.

The symptoms I am seeing is if I am logged in as one user lets say Test123 and is friends with Test321 who is also logged in, one of them will say online while the other doesn't. Whichever page I refresh that user goes online and the other goes offline.

Here are my components FrontEnd:

FriendsPage.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


import { useAuth } from "../../context/AuthContext/AuthContext";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
import gps from "../GlobalPageStyles.module.scss";
import socket from "../../context/SocketClient/socketClient";

interface User {
  _id: string;
  username: string;
  online?: boolean;
}

interface FriendOnlineStatus {
  userId: string;
  status: boolean;
}

const FriendsPage: React.FC = () => {
  const [friendsList, setFriendsList] = useState<User[]>([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>("");
  const [pendingRequests, setPendingRequests] = useState<
    Array<{ _id: string; username: string }>
  >([]);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<User[]>([]);
  const [showFriendRemoveWarning, setShowFriendRemoveWarning] = useState(false);
  const [selectedFriendIdRemoval, setSelectedFriendIdRemoval] = useState<
    string | null
  >(null);
  const { _id, token, username, isLoggedIn } = useAuth();

  // Fetch friends list from mongodb
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchFriends() {
      const headers: { [key: string]: string } = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      };

      if (token) {
        headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      }

      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3001/friends/friendsList",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: headers,
        }
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      setFriendsList(data.friendsList);
    }
    // Fetch list initially
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      fetchFriends();
    }
    // Setup socket listener for real-time updates
    const handleFriendsListUpdate = () => {
      fetchFriends();
    };

    socket.on("updateFriendsList", handleFriendsListUpdate);

    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      socket.off("updateFriendsList", handleFriendsListUpdate);
    };
  }, [socket, token]);

  //Fetch Initial search after freinds list loads
  useEffect(() => {
    handleSearch();
  }, [friendsList]);

  // FetchFriendRequests function
  const fetchFriendRequests = async () => {
    if (username) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `http://localhost:3001/friends/friendRequests/${username}`
        );
        const friendRequests = await response.json();
        setPendingRequests(friendRequests);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching friend requests:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  // useEffect for initial fetch of friends request and real-time updates
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFriendRequests(); // Fetch friend requests initially

    const handleFriendRequestsUpdate = () => {
      console.log(
        "Received 'updatePendingRequests' event from server. Fetching new data..."
      );
      fetchFriendRequests(); // Fetch updated friend requests
    };

    socket.on("updatePendingRequests", handleFriendRequestsUpdate);

    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      socket.off("updatePendingRequests", handleFriendRequestsUpdate);
    };
  }, [username, socket]);

  // Search usernames
  const handleSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3001/friends/search?username=${searchTerm}`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, // assuming you have the token variable set up as before
          },
        }
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
      }
      // let data = await response.json();
      // const friendIds = friendsList.map(friend => friend.username); // Assuming friend object has _id field
      // data = data.filter(user: string => !friendIds.includes(user.username));
      // setSearchResults(data);
      const data: User[] = await response.json();
      // Filter out friends from the search results
      const friendUsernames = friendsList.map((friend) => friend.username); // Assuming each friend object has a username field
      const filteredData = data.filter(
        (user) => !friendUsernames.includes(user.username)
      );

      setSearchResults(filteredData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Fetch error:", error);
    }
  };

  // Get users by Id
  const getUserId = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/getUserId", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      return data.userId;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  // Send a freind request
  const handleSendRequest = async (receiverId: string) => {
    const senderId = await getUserId();
    if (!senderId) {
      console.error("Sender ID not found");
      return;
    }
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3001/friends/sendRequest",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ senderId, receiverId }),
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Error sending friend request");
      }

      // Handle successful request, like updating UI or state
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      // Handle error, such as showing an error message
    }
    socket.emit("sendFriendRequest", { senderId, receiverId });
  };

  // Listening for a Friend Request response event from the server
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("friendRequestSent", (online) => {
      // Handle the response, like updating UI
      console.log("Friend request sent:", online);
    });

    // Corrected cleanup function
    return () => {
      socket.off("friendRequestSent");
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleFriendOnlineStatusUpdate = ({
      userId,
      status,
    }: FriendOnlineStatus) => {
      console.log(userId, status);
      setFriendsList((currentList) =>
        currentList.map((friend) =>
          friend._id === userId ? { ...friend, online: status } : friend
        )
      );
    };

    socket.on("friendOnlineStatusUpdate", handleFriendOnlineStatusUpdate);

    return () => {
      socket.off("friendOnlineStatusUpdate", handleFriendOnlineStatusUpdate);
    };
  }, [socket, isLoggedIn]);

  // Accept a freind request
  const handleAcceptRequest = async (friendId: string) => {
    const userId = await getUserId();
    if (!userId) {
      console.error("User ID not found");
      return;
    }
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3001/friends/acceptRequest`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ userId, friendId }),
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        // Remove the accepted request from the pending requests
        setPendingRequests((prevRequests) =>
          prevRequests.filter((req) => req.username !== friendId)
        );
      } else {
        console.error("Error accepting request");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
    socket.emit("acceptFriendRequest", { userId, friendId });
  };

  // reject freind request
  const handleRejectRequest = async (requesterId: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3001/friends/rejectRequest`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ requesterId }),
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        // Remove the rejected request from the pending requests
        setPendingRequests((prevRequests) =>
          prevRequests.filter((req) => req.username !== username)
        );
      } else {
        console.error("Error rejecting request");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  // Remove friend
  const handleRemoveFriendRequest = async (friendId: string | null) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3001/friends/removeFriend`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ friendId }),
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        // Remove the friend from the local state to update UI
        setFriendsList((prevList) =>
          prevList.filter((friend) => friend._id !== friendId)
        );
      } else {
        console.error("Error removing friend");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  // Removal Popup warning
  const handleRemoveFriend = (friendId: string) => {
    setSelectedFriendIdRemoval(friendId);
    setShowFriendRemoveWarning(true);
  };

  const confirmRemoveFriend = async () => {
    handleRemoveFriendRequest(selectedFriendIdRemoval);
    setSelectedFriendIdRemoval(null);
    setShowFriendRemoveWarning(false);
  };

  const cancelRemoveFriend = () => {
    setSelectedFriendIdRemoval(null);
    setShowFriendRemoveWarning(false);
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Friends</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <div className={gps.topMargin}></div>
        <IonLabel>Friends List</IonLabel>

        {friendsList?.length <= 0 ? (
          <IonList>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel>Add some friends!</IonLabel>
            </IonItem>
          </IonList>
        ) : (
          <IonList>
            {friendsList.map((friend) => (
              <IonItem key={friend._id}>
                <IonAvatar slot="start">
                  {/* Replace with avatar image if available */}
                  <img
                    src={`https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?text=${friend.username}`}
                  />
                </IonAvatar>
                <IonLabel>
                  {friend.username}

                  <IonBadge color={friend.online ? "success" : "medium"}>
                    {friend.online ? "Online" : "Offline"}
                  </IonBadge>
                </IonLabel>
                <IonButton
                  fill="clear"
                  onClick={() => handleRemoveFriend(friend._id)}
                >
                  Remove
                  <IonIcon slot="icon-only" icon={closeCircleOutline} />
                </IonButton>
              </IonItem>
            ))}{" "}
          </IonList>
        )}
        {/* Friend removal warning */}
        <IonAlert
          isOpen={showFriendRemoveWarning}
          onDidDismiss={() => setShowFriendRemoveWarning(false)}
          header={"Confirm Removal"}
          message={"Are you sure you want to remove this friend?"}
          buttons={[
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              role: "cancel",
              cssClass: "secondary",
              handler: cancelRemoveFriend,
            },
            {
              text: "Yes, Remove",
              handler: confirmRemoveFriend,
            },
          ]}
        />

        {/* Pending Friend Requests */}
        {pendingRequests?.length <= 0 ? null : (
          <>
            <IonLabel>Pending Friend Requests</IonLabel>
            <IonList>
              {pendingRequests.map((request) => (
                <IonItem key={request.username}>
                  <IonLabel>{request.username}</IonLabel>
                  <IonButton
                    fill="clear"
                    onClick={() => handleAcceptRequest(request._id)}
                  >
                    <IonIcon slot="icon-only" icon={checkmarkCircleOutline} />
                  </IonButton>
                  <IonButton
                    fill="clear"
                    onClick={() => handleRejectRequest(request._id)}
                  >
                    <IonIcon slot="icon-only" icon={closeCircleOutline} />
                  </IonButton>
                </IonItem>
              ))}
            </IonList>
          </>
        )}

        {/* Search Input Item */}
        <IonLabel>Search Friends</IonLabel>
        <IonList>
          <IonItem>
            <IonLabel>Search Usernames:</IonLabel>
            <IonInput
              value={searchTerm}
              placeholder="Enter username"
              onIonInput={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.detail.value ?? "")}
            />
            <IonButton onClick={handleSearch}>Search</IonButton>
          </IonItem>

          {/* Search Results */}
          <div style={{ maxHeight: "300px", overflowY: "auto" }}>
            {searchResults.map((user) => (
              <IonItem key={user._id}>
                <IonLabel>{user.username}</IonLabel>
                <IonButton onClick={() => handleSendRequest(user._id)}>
                  Add Friend
                </IonButton>
              </IonItem>
            ))}
          </div>
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default FriendsPage;
```

socketClient.tsx:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

// Initiate connection to socket server
const socket = io("http://localhost:3001"); 

// Connect
socket.on("connect", () => {});

// Handle online status updates of friends
socket.on("friendOnlineStatusUpdate", ({ userId, status }) => {
  console.log(`Friend's status updated - User ID: ${userId}, Status: ${status}`);
  // Update the UI or state accordingly
});

// Total online users
socket.on("totalConnectedUsers", (usersCount) => {});

// Send friend request
socket.on("sendFriendRequest",  (senderId, receiverId) => {} );


export default socket;
```

AuthContext.tsx:

```
import socket from "../SocketClient/socketClient";

interface AuthContextType {
  _id: string | null;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  username: string | null;
  token: string | null;
  login: (username: string, accessToken: string, _id: string) => void;
  logout: () => void;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({
  _id: null,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  username: null,
  token: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

export const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  return context;
};

interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [_id, set_Id] = useState<string | null>(localStorage.getItem("_id"));
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(
    local

Storage.getItem("isLoggedIn") === "true"
  );
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string | null>(
    localStorage.getItem("username")
  );
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(
    localStorage.getItem("accessToken")
  );


  const login = (username: string, accessToken: string, _id: string) => {
    set_Id(_id);
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    setUsername(username);
    setToken(accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem("_id", _id);
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    set_Id(null);
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    setUsername(null);
    setToken(null);
    localStorage.removeItem("_id");
    localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn");
    localStorage.removeItem("username");
    localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      // If the user is logged in
      socket.emit('updateOnlineStatus',  _id,  true );
    } else {
      // If the user is not logged in or logs out
      if (_id) { // Check if there's an ID available
        socket.emit('updateOnlineStatus',  _id, false );
      }
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn, _id]);
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ _id, isLoggedIn, username, token, login, logout }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

And on the Backend:

PlayerModel.js:

```
//PLAYER MODEL

const playerSchema = require('./PlayerSchema');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Static method to find user by email and password
playerSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async function(email, password) {
    const user = await this.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error('Unable to login');
    }
  
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      throw new Error('Unable to login');
    }
  
    return user;
  };
  
  // Hash the plain text password before saving
  playerSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const user = this;
    if (user.isModified('password')) {
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
    }
    next();
  });

// Add friend requests and friends arrays to the schema
playerSchema.add({
  friendRequests: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }],
  friends: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }]
});

// Use the schema to create a model.
const Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);

module.exports = Player;
```

PlayerSchema.js:

```
//PLAYER SCHEMA

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'); // Make sure to install bcryptjs

const playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  token: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  gameWins: {
    type: Number,
    require: false,
    unique: false,
  },
  gameLosses: {
    type: Number,
    require: false,
    unique: false,
  },
  friendsList: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Player'
  }],
  friendRequests: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Player'
  }],
  online: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});


module.exports = playerSchema;
```

socketController.js:

```
//SOCKET CONTROLLER

const gameSessionManager = require("../matchmaking/gameSessionManager");
const StateManager = require("../networking/sync/stateManager");
const reconcileClientState = require("../networking/sync/reconciliation");
const compensateForLag = require("../networking/latency/lagCompensation");
const validateGameActions = require("../validation/validateGameActions");
const Player = require("../database/PlayerModel");

// Initialize the state manager
const stateManager = new StateManager();

// This will store unique socket IDs of connected users
const totalConnectedUsers = new Set();

//Single User online status
const userOnlineStatus = new Map(); // Key: ObjectId, Value: socket.id

// Initialize a matchmaking queue
let matchmakingQueue = [];

module.exports = function (socket, io) {
  // Listen to change stream for the Player collection
  const changeStream = Player.watch();
  changeStream
    .on("change", (change) => {
      if (
        change.operationType === "update" &&
        change.updateDescription.updatedFields.friendRequests
      ) {
        const updatedUserId = change.documentKey._id.toString();

        // Emit event to the specific user whose friendRequest array changed
        const userSocketId = userOnlineStatus.get(updatedUserId);
        io.to(userSocketId).emit("updatePendingRequests");
      }
      if (
        change.operationType === "update" &&
        change.updateDescription.updatedFields.friendsList
      ) {
        const updatedUserId = change.documentKey._id.toString();
        const userSocketId = userOnlineStatus.get(updatedUserId);
        io.to(userSocketId).emit("updateFriendsList");
      }
      if (
        change.operationType === "update" &&
        change.updateDescription.updatedFields.online
      ) {
        const updatedUserId = change.documentKey._id.toString();
        const userSocketId = userOnlineStatus.get(updatedUserId);
      }
    })
    .on("error", (error) => {
      console.error("Error in change stream:", error);
    });

  // Total Connected Users
  totalConnectedUsers.add(socket.id);
  io.emit("totalConnectedUsers", totalConnectedUsers.size);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User disconnected, removing socket ID:", socket.id);
    totalConnectedUsers.delete(socket.id);
    io.emit("totalConnectedUsers", totalConnectedUsers.size);
  });

  // Handle user connection
  socket.on("updateOnlineStatus", async (userId, status) => {
    userOnlineStatus.set(userId.toString(), socket.id);
    console.log("Storing socket ID for user:", userId, "Socket ID:", socket.id);
    await Player.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { online: status });
    checkAndEmitUserStatus(userId, status, io);

    // Find the user's friends
    const user = await Player.findById(userId).populate('friendsList');
    console.log("Current userOnlineStatus map:", userOnlineStatus);
    user.friendsList.forEach(friend => {
      console.log("Looking up socket ID for friend:", friend._id.toString());
        const friendSocketId = userOnlineStatus.get(friend._id.toString());
        if (friendSocketId) {
            io.to(friendSocketId).emit("friendOnlineStatusUpdate", { userId, status });
        }
    });
  });

//   Friend request
  socket.on("sendFriendRequest", async (data) => {
    const { senderId, receiverId } = data;
    try {
      // Assume sendFriendRequest is a function that handles the request logic
      const newRequest = await sendFriendRequest(senderId, receiverId);

      // Get the receiver's socket ID from userOnlineStatus
      const receiverSocketId = userOnlineStatus.get(receiverId);

      // Check if the receiver is online (socket ID is available)
      if (receiverSocketId) {
        io.to(receiverSocketId).emit("friendRequestReceived", newRequest);
      } else {
        // Handle the case when the receiver is offline
        console.log("Receiver is offline");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      socket.emit("friendRequestError", error.message);
    }
  });

  // Accept friend request handler
  socket.on("acceptFriendRequest", async (data) => {
    const { userId, friendId } = data;

    try {
      // Assume acceptFriendRequest is a function that updates the friendship status
      await acceptFriendRequest(userId, friendId);

      // Notify the friend that the request has been accepted
      const friendSocketId = userOnlineStatus.get(friendId);
      if (friendSocketId) {
        io.to(friendSocketId).emit("friendRequestAccepted", {
          userId,
          friendId,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      socket.emit("friendRequestError", error.message);
    }
  });
};

// Call to check user online status
function checkAndEmitUserStatus(userId, status, io) {
  io.emit("userOnlineStatus", { userId, status });
}
```

Finally, server.js:

```
//SERVER

require('dotenv').config();
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const app = require('./expressApp'); // Import the Express app
const socketController = require('../socket/socketController'); 
const matchmakingService = require('../matchmaking/matchmakingService');

const server = http.createServer(app);



// Base socket setup
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", // Allow your frontend origin
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
});

// Online total users count socket
let onlineUsersCount = 0;
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  onlineUsersCount++;
  io.emit('updateOnlineUsers', onlineUsersCount);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    onlineUsersCount--;
    io.emit('updateOnlineUsers', onlineUsersCount);
  });
  socketController(socket, io); // Pass 'io' to manage broadcasts/emits

  socket.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Socket.io error:', error);
  });
  socket.on('requestOnlineUsersCount', () => {
    socket.emit('updateOnlineUsers', onlineUsersCount);
  });
});

// Online Single user by ObjectId
const connectedUsers = new Map(); // Key: ObjectId, Value: socket.id


// Match making socket
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New client connected');
  require('../socket/socketController')(socket, io);
  // Additional socket event listeners...
});
// Start matchmaking process
matchmakingService.startMatchmaking();

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('joinMatchmaking', (data) => {
    console.log('User joining matchmaking from server.js:', data.userId);
    // Add matchmaking logic here
  });
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```